# PHP Xpath Doesn't Obtain Count Function

Tags: php, xpath, domxpath

**Update**

To avoid delete this question, after a few comments I realized that, PHP uses Xpath 1.0 so I was trying to use functions from Xpath version 2.0.

Thanks for your feedback and hope some high reputation users suggest me if it's better to delete the question or leave it with this update.

---

I have been searching this problem but none of the solutions posted worked for me. I'm using DomXPath in PHP and I have used the **Template Tester for Xpath 2.0** to test my queries: http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi

This is the first part of the code to start working on it:

```
   $dom_html = new DOMDocument();
   libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
   $dom_html->loadHTMLFile($file);
   libxml_clear_errors();
   $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom_html);
```

Then I try this query in the Xpath 2.0 Tester:

```
//table/tbody/tr/td/div/count(table)
```

This query give me the amount of  that each div has inside of it and it's a perfect solution for me:

`11
2
1
1
2
14
4
19
4
4
3
2
9
16`

But when I tried to make the same in PHP, I have not obtain those numbers. I have trying the following solutions:

```
$quantity  = $xpath->evaluate('count(//table/tbody/tr/td/div/table)');
```

But this give me the total count and not give me the desired solution.

```
$quantity  = $xpath->query('//table/tbody/tr/td/div/count(table)');
```

When I make this query, I tried using two different ways to obtain mi desired answer but none of them works for me:

1)

```
foreach ($quantity as $content)  
{   
  echo $content->nodeValue; 
}
```

2)

```
foreach ($quantity as $content) 
{
   echo $contenido->textContent;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure it's relevant here, but note that [libxml, which is used by all PHP's standard XML extensions](http://www.xmlsoft.org/) only supports XPath 1.0, not 2.0

Comment: @IMSoP, it is relevant as calling a function in the last step (e.g. `div/count(table)` is possible in XPath 2.0 (and yields a sequence of xs:integer values) but is not a legal XPath 1.0 expression.

Comment: Totally agree with you, I see that thanks.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Aha, my first thought was to post it as an answer, but I don't know enough about XPath to recognise that as a 2.0-only feature. :)

Comment: Would you consider answering your own question?